# type conversion in embedded C

Tags: c, type-conversion

x is a variable, and its type is int, and I need to convert the type of x from int to long or float. But a simple typecasting (long) x;  is not working. Only the following line is working: *((long*) &(x));  (I copy it from another parts of the code.)

```
int x;
(long) x; --> it is not working
*((long*) &(x)); --> it is working
```

I know what `(long) x;` means, but...

1. Could you please describe in detail what `*((long*) &(x));` mean exactly? How does it work?
2. Why it is working and why the simple version not?

It is an embedded code, and I am new in embedded system developing.

```
main(){
    float k;
    int i=1, j=2;

    k = GetSum(i,j);
}



float GetSum(int x, int y){
    float z;
    z = *((float*) &(x)) + *((float*) &(y)); /*it is working --> compile with this line*/
    z = (float)x + (float)y;                /*it is not working --> not compile with this line*/
    return z;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working" exactly? How are you using those expressions?

Comment: You can't alter the type of the variable. At most you may copy its value (suitably converted) to a variable of another type.

Comment: Not enough code.   Also not enough explanation of how you think it should work. The `(long)&x` notation converts an address to a `long` which is dangerous on Win64.  You need to provide more of an MCVE ([MCVE]).

Comment: Could you please show `lvalue` or left side operand of your code where you are using `(long)x`.

Comment: "a simple typecasting (long) x; is not working. Only the following line is working: ((long) &(x));" - this does not make any sense. What are you trying to do? What does "not working" mean?

Comment: The second version is definitely not working, since it invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: That code is so bug-laden and error prone it doesn't bear thinking about.  It is horrifying that you are compiling with options that let it run.

Comment: @Gerhardh: I only changed formatting. You can verify that in the markdown diff. (The fact that `*` outside code blocks renders italics might have been the source of some confusion.)

Comment: @Mat, I have to appoligize! You are right. I got fooled by the rendering of the code..

Comment: @Lundin: Programs with behavior not defined by the C standard can work. Not everybody uses “strictly conforms to the C standard” as an alias for “satisfies the requirements of my task.” In fact, the OP refers to [embedded C](http://www.differencebetween.info/difference-between-c-and-embedded-c), so you should expect there are behaviors not defined by C but defined by embedded C.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I don't think that report ever made it to an ISO standard, or at least nobody uses it and there are no compilers for it. Extremely more likely, the OP refers to using ISO 9899 for embedded systems ("freestanding implementations"), in which case the code doesn't make sense and invokes multiple cases of UB.

Comment: @Lundin: All over the world, people are programming to specifications other than ISO standards. Some of them even make up new languages. The OP does not refer to ISO 9899 except by using the C tag (and there is no embedded C tag, so that was as close as possible). They used “embedded C” in the title. Embedded C is a standard of its own. Insisting that all code using C has to use only standard C is absurd. There is no such requirement in the world generally, and it is completely possible to do high-quality engineering using other specifications.

Comment: @EricPostpischil From tag wiki usage: "Unless the question explicitly mentions which version of the C standard that is used, it is assumed that the current version is used. That is, whichever version of ISO 9899 that ISO currently lists as active. Please have this in mind when answering or **commenting** on questions tagged C."  Are you saying that the C tag should be removed? There is nothing in the post indicating that this is _not_ ISO C.

Comment: @Lundin: The language is explicitly stated in the title, which says “embedded C.”

Comment: @EricPostpischil Might as well refer to the use of C in embedded systems. Feel free to create a new tag [tag:embedded-c]. And then afterwards, create some compilers for it too, so the tag - as well as this discussion - turn meaningful.

Comment: @Lundin: There are compilers for it. And a published standard.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Off you go to create a tag for that language then.

Comment: @Lundin: The OP with 6 reputation could not have created a tag, so interpreting their question as if it could have used a tag that did not exist is an error.

Answer (score 3):

The type of variables is fixed when they are declared.   Type conversion doesn't affect that.

So

```
 int x;
 (long)x;
```

doesn't change the type of `x`.   It converts the *value of* `x` to a `long`.   So, if `y` is of type `long`.

```
 y = (long)x;
```

converts the value of `x` to a value of type `long`, and stores the result of that conversion in `y`.

To understand what `*((long*) &(x))` does ....

- Firstly `&(x)` computes the address of `x`  (the `()` are unnecessary).   That address is of type `int *`, since `x` is of type `int`.
- The `(long *)` then converts that pointer to be a pointer to `long` (i.e. a `long *`)
- The `*` around `((long*) &(x))` then dereferences that `long *`.   This effectively tells the compiler to act *as if* that memory location which contains an `int` actually contains a `long`.

If you then use that, for example;

```
y = *((long*) &(x));        /*  store the value retrieved into y
```

or

```
*((long*) &(x)) = 42L;      /*  treat the memory occupied by x AS IF it is a long, 
                                and write 42L to that memory   */
```

then the result in both cases is formally undefined behaviour.    The C standard does not describe any constraints on what happens.

The first treats the memory occupied by `x` *as if* it contains a `long`.   The problem is that a `long` may occupy more memory than an `int`.   A typical symptom in such a case is a garbage value stored in `y`.

The second writes the value `42L` to the memory occupied by `x`, treating that memory AS IF it contains a `long`.  If `long` is larger than an `int`, two common results are program crashes (the program modifying memory past `x` and the operating system therefore terminating the program) or data poisoning  (an unrelated variable in your program, that happens to be located in memory just after `x`, has its value changed).

If it "seems to work" (however you define "work") with your testing then you are getting lucky - for example, `long` and `int` happen to be the same size and same representation WITH YOUR PARTICULAR COMPILER.    However, the behaviour is still undefined, anything can actually happen - such as code working with one compiler, but crashing when built with another.

Answer (score 1):

Compile with warnings enabled. The reason for failure must be that you're using an obsolete compiler that supports **implicit function declarations** that were forbidden by C99, i.e. **18 years ago** , and C thinks that it is **`int`** `GetSum()` and since the function actually returns **float**, your code just has undefined  behaviour.

Your function would "work" with the *latter*, i.e.

```
z = (float)x + (float)y;
```

if you changed the return type to `int`.

---

Please just stop writing code that uses conventions that belong to Dark Middle Ages. If you use `gcc`, compile with `-std=c99` or `-std=c11` or similar, and with `-pedantic-errors`. The year is 2017 (for a few more days).

Answer (score -1):

`int x;` is a *declaration* of a variable; you reserve storage space for it.

Your other lines are not declarations. They are expressions. These expressions can only be used in another expression or in the *assignment* to another variable, for example:

```
long l = (long) x;
double d = (double) ((long)x/1234);
```